# c# nuget package doesn't show up in references in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, reference, nuget

I want to create a C# app that does things with the powershell. I found many solutions on the internet how to do that [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887619/10122822). The most answeres to this use the [Powershell class from 'Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). Now when I search this package in nuget and install it, it doesnt show up in the references list in visual studio and also the using statement or the 'quick fix' on a PowerShell object doesnt find it.

Did I install something wrong or do I need something else too?

---

Edit for more infos:

- .net Version 4.6.1
- Tried 'Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime'v 7.0.0 and 7.0.3
- 'Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime' is downloaded and avaible at './packages/Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime.7.0.0'
- 'packages.config' does contain the entry for 'Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime'.

Comment: Create a new .net core 3.1 project to consume this package, the package will show up normally then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the assembly within the package targets `.net core 3.1` instead of `.net framework 4.6.1`. So you can't see the reference in solution explorer.

It's **by design of the package author**, you can [download the package manually](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime/7.0.0), rename the name from `xx.nupkg` to `xx.zip` to check the content of the package.

**The structure of the package:**

[image]

**And the content of the Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime.nuspec file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.1" />
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```